# How can I scale bezier points without curve anchors being affected?

Tags: transforms

I made a circle, then went into edit mode. Selected two opposing points and went to scale. I'd like to prevent the amount of curve from being affected. I just want to move points uniformly.

I hope that makes sense.

Without restricting the anchors (using the circle as an example object), if you were to scale the two opposing anchors you'd end up with a peanut shape (due to the curves also scaling). What I want is to end up with an oblong oval -- using edit mode. I know I can achieve the same effect in this case by scaling along the x or y axis in this case in object mode but I figure for more complex shapes this would not be the case.

Comment: For someone who wants to do the same thing but in Graph Editor and Google take you to here. You can scale bezier points of one keyframe. But if you want to scale bezier points of multiple keyframes. There is an addon called Relative Ease, made by Fede.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the points handles type is set to *Automatic* by default. You can try convert them to ***Free*** before you scale it.
To do so, in *Edit Mode* of any *Curve* object :

- Select the points you want to scale
- Hit <kbd>V</kbd> (or menu: `Curve` > `Control Points` > `Set Handle Type`) and choose ***Free***. The handles change color.
- you can now scale points the way you want, constraining them or not, and the handles won't scale accordingly. They will keep their original alignment.
- Beware to don't change their type again to *Automatic*, because it will re-scale them according to their point's new position.

Comment: Still seems when I scale the points the handles follow -- no matter what handle type is chosen. Although if I "grab" the points the handles respond correctly. I was hoping there was a way to do this so I could still use scale (when moving multiple points, since I don't want to "grab" them in the same direction).

Comment: Apologies I was scaling on multiple axes!

Answer (score 1):

After scaling constraint to x-axis in *Edit Mode* the curve gets a 'waist' this can easily be fixed by scaling the control points. In *Object Mode* the constriction does not appear.

If you only need the curves for modeling more complex objects and want adjust the scale, converting the curve into a mesh could be also an option <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (in *Object Mode*).

[image]

Comment: I knew how to do that, and thank you. I was hoping there was a way to constrain how the scale worked. Since this is a very simple case the manual option isn't that annoying.

Comment: I'd also like to add -- all 4 points' handles scaled. So you end up with something that doesn't look like an oval. I'm coming from an illustrator mind set (including the app of the same name and how it handles vector design.)

Answer (score 1):

You can select those points, and press <kbd>V</kbd> to change the handle type to **Free** or **Aligned**, then you can scale them along single axis without messing up the original handle.